# My files on my Google Drive disappeared but are still searchable and use up my quota?

Tags: google-drive

Background: My Google account X was getting full so I tried to delete some files from the Google Drive part of the account. A and B are folders, X and Y are accounts.

I had a folder A on my Google account X that I tried to move to another Google account Y. To do this I shared the A with Y with the intention to remove A from X and store it on Y instead. I can't recall all operations I performed and in which order but approximately something like this:

- I made a new folder B on Y
- Moved all files from the (shared) folder A to B (logged in to account Y)
- Moved A, with all its content, to the Trash on account X and emptied the Trash

After doing this I realised that the files that originally were in A on X but now are in B on Y still were marked as shared, the owner of these files was set to X and that X was still full. However, I couldn't find any of the files on X using the regular file browser but I could search for them and find them.

Normally, if you look at the info panel for a file there is a field that indicates its parent:

[image]

Even when you look at an item in the root folder you can see this

[image]

But in the case with the files that originally were in A, this is how it looks when I found them through searching in account X

[image]

**Where are those files?**

I can search for the files on X and delete them but there were a couple of hundreds of them so it is a PITA and it's very likely that I won't find all of them/by mistake find some files that shouldn't be deleted and delete them.

I should also add that *Shared with me* is empty on Y.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Drive, files only take up storage space in one account—the owner of the files. If you want to transfer ownership to a different account, you can do that individually, for each file, in each file's sharing settings. If you want to transfer ownership for an entire Drive, try either to:

- contact Google support to ask them if they can do this (and please report back here what they said), or
- takeout / download all your files, and re-upload the files into the new account (Google Docs Editors will be converted to MS Office), or
- transfer files to a shared drive in G Suite, then to the new account (folders cannot be moved to a shared drive). This would help with changing the ownership of multiple Google Docs Editors at the same time.

---

Regarding what happened to your files, they were orphaned inside the original account. You can search for them with [`is:unorganized`](https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=is:unorganized).